# React native Expo TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to fetch data from local API that is generated by ASP.NET Web API application. This local API works fine when it is tested by Postman program but it doesn't work with my react native project. I searched for this error and I found that I should replace "localhost" by my machine IPv4 address, I did so but I still get the same error. I run my project using Expo on my mobile that has Android version 7.0 NRD90M 
Here's my code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
const EXAMPLE_ENDPOINT = "http://192.168.1.5:57975/api/values/5";
class TestAPI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        value: null
     }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
     this._fetchExampleAsync();
  }
 _fetchExampleAsync = async () => {
    try {
          let response = await fetch(EXAMPLE_ENDPOINT);
          let result = await response.json();
          this.setState({value});
        } catch(e) {
        this.setState({value: e});
     }
  };
  render() {
      console.log("Value: ", this.state.value);
      return (
         <Container>
           <Content contentContainerStyle={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
             <Text>Test fetch API</Text>
             <Text>values: {JSON.stringify(this.state.value)}</Text>
           </Content>
         </Container>
      );
   }
 }
 export default TestAPI;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it with type: **'multipart/form-data'**:

```
var media = {uri: photo.uri ,type: 'multipart/form-data', name: filename, };
```